# Hyperparameter tuning one-class svm

Tags: svm, cross-validation, anomaly-detection, hyperparameter-tuning

I have a problem where I am trying to apply a one-class svm to detect outliers. I am training on a dataset of *true* cases using a one-class radial svm and then predicting for both false and true cases. It is worth noting that the *true* cases I am training on do contain a proportion of misclassified cases. This is the nature of the problem and not something that can be corrected for or identified easily.

I have applied hyperparameter tuning through a grid search with cross-validation to get the best values of `nu` and `gamma` for the model. However, when I do this and predict on all cases, I get poor separability between true and false cases based on the resulting decision values. I actually get far better separability from using a fixed value for `C` and `gamma` of 1 and 0.05 respectively.
My intuition is that this lack of separability is down to the misclassified cases in the *true* training data. As such, my question is should hyperparameter tuning be applied to a one-class svm on data with misclassified values? If so, should `nu` and `gamma` both be tuned?  Any papers discussing this problem would be great as I haven't found any resources relating to it.

I am aware that nu is related to C by `nu = A+B/C` where A, B are constants that are difficult to calculate and that

> The parameter nu is an upper bound on the fraction of margin errors
>   and a lower bound of the fraction of support vectors relative to the
>   total number of training examples

So `nu` of 0.01 would mean at most 1% of your training examples would be misclassified. A good discussion on `nu` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230955/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-nu-parameter-in-scikit-learns-svm-class). I am searching values `0.0001 0.0010 0.0100 0.0500 0.1000 0.1500 0.2000 0.2500 0.3000 0.3500 0.4000 0.4500 0.5000`.
I am also aware that

> Gamma is a parameter of the RBF kernel and can be thought of as the
>   ‘spread’ of the kernel and therefore the decision region. When gamma
>   is low, the ‘curve’ of the decision boundary is very low and thus the
>   decision region is very broad. When gamma is high, the ‘curve’ of the
>   decision boundary is high, which creates islands of
>   decision-boundaries around data points.

A good post on gamma with intuitive visualisations is [here](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/support_vector_machines/svc_parameters_using_rbf_kernel/). I am searching across gamma values of `1x10^-04 1x10^-03 1x10^-02 1x10^-01 1x10^+00 1x10^+01 1x10^+02 1x10^+03 1x10^+04 1x10^+05`

So should I hold `nu` constant at a high value to assume a high number of misclassified cases? Also should I search across different values of gamma?